# How do I access pallet constants from polkadot-js?

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet

For example, [the utility pallet has a constant called `batched_calls_limit`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/f233671c27aa2ec4256156d78b57cb153a4e2e5e/packages/types-support/src/metadata/v14/substrate-json.json#L305). How do I access this from polkadot-js?

```
        {
          "name": "Utility",
          "storage": null,
          "calls": {
            "type": 125
          },
          "events": {
            "type": 29
          },
          "constants": [
            {
              "name": "batched_calls_limit",
              "type": 4,
              "value": "0xaa2a0000",
              "docs": [
                " The limit on the number of batched calls."
              ]
            }
          ],
          "errors": {
            "type": 414
          },
          "index": 1
        },
```

The docs cryptically state that its available in constant metadata.

```
       * - `calls`: The calls to be dispatched from the same origin. The number of call must not
       * exceed the constant: `batched_calls_limit` (available in constant metadata).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Utility constant(s) like this:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

export const getUtilityConstants = async () => {

    const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

    const utilityConstants = await api.consts.utility;
    console.dir(utilityConstants, { depth: 5 });
    console.log(utilityConstants.batchedCallsLimit.toHuman());
}
```